# FInd Out if User Switched off Document and Data From iCloud Account

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, icloud

Once again stuck in iCloud :(. I am using Core Data + iCloud and in my app i want to know if user switched off Document and Data from his account.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in support for detecting this change, only for detecting if the user has logged out. One common approach is to write a sentinel file to iCloud, separately from Core Data, and then monitor that file to see if it disappears. Details vary but it's usually something like:

1. Write the file using `NSFileManager` iCloud calls, and store the file name in user defaults. Each device using the account will have a different file, so including a UUID in the file name is a good idea. You only write this file, you never change it.
2. Use either `NSFilePresenter` or `NSMetadataQuery` to get notified of changes to that file-- like, if it disappears.

If the file disappears, take immediate steps to unload the entire Core Data stack, including every managed object, because they don't have a persistent store backing them up any more.

One sample implementation is in [Black Pixel's version of the Core Data "Recipes" demo app](https://github.com/blackpixel/NSConferenceiPhoneCoreDataRecipes). You might need to tweak it to get it to work right in your code.

Comment: Ya i already did this thing, But my problem is for Document and Data is set to off. Any work around for that

Comment: Using a sentinel file *is* the workaround for users turning documents and data off.

Comment: NSMetadataQuery is evil. It requires a run loop and has to do its work on the main thread. Using a sync'd sentinel file won't work for detecting account changes (or the delete all button) as another peer could delete it willingly. The file needs to be in a .nosync.

Answer (score 1):

There are two cases:

1. The app is not running, or in the background when the account status changes.

The solution here is to store / compare the identity token using NSUserDefaults (or some other storage local to the app). Grab the identity token from NSFileManager and compare it to the cached value each time the app finishes launching or comes back to the foreground.

```
id token = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken];
```

1. The app is running when the account changes.

This requires a file presenter to "something" inside the container. The best solution is to use a file that *is not* synced.

Implement -accommodatePresentedItemDeletionWithCompletionHandler: to spawn a thread (dispatch_async works great) and do your cleanup work.

Comment: ubiquityIdentityToken is IOS6 feature. My app support IOS5 also

Comment: for iOS 5 you're relegated to calling -[NSFileManager URLForUbiquitousContainerIdentifier:] to discover if there is an active account on the device. This can take a long time.